# How to deploy generate multiple dist folders in angular app?

Tags: angular, azure, express

I have an angular application that includes a separate folder of a an express server , I want to deploy both the angular app and the server inside it to Azure , for that purpose I need to generate two dist folders that will be deployed simultaneously on Azure. How can I generate two dist folders ?

Here is my code structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your application is designed, you have the following options

- **Regular Angular App**
  For the standard scenario, you have 2 ways to go about this

  1. **Deploy Angular bits to [blob storage as a static website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website)**
     This is something I would recommend considering that your static assets (compiled js, css, html, etc.) would be served from very high performance servers and top of that, you could drive request through [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#content-delivery-network-cdn-and-secure-socket-layer-ssl-support) for global scale and really low latencies.
  2. **Deploy Angular bits along with your express app**
     This is a simpler deployment requiring you to have your express app serve the angular built files [as static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

     > BONUS: Do consider making your app a [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) for a much better user experience which can also be served as static content and allows your app to work offline as well
- **[Server Side Rendered Angular App](https://angular.io/guide/universal)**
  I guess this isn't what you have but if you do, then its a matter of just deploying the app is.